# Custom legend for bubble plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, spatial, bubble-chart

I have a dataframe which contains a spatial variable with simulated and observed values.

```
df <- data.frame(sim = sample((20:30),10),
                 obs = sample(25:40,10),
                 long = rnorm(10,10,8),
                 lat = rnorm(10,30,15))
```

I have plotted a spatial bubble plot using the following code.

```
ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = shp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
             col = "black", lwd = 0.8, fill = "slategray1",
             alpha = 0.5) +
coord_cartesian() + 
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = sim, size = sim), col = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = obs, size = obs), col = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
scale_size_continuous(range = c(10,20)) +
coord_map(xlim = c(-1, 22), ylim = c(10, 45))
```

The output of the above code is in the image. What I want to show in the plot is the difference between the simulated and observed data which is done perfectly. Now, I want to show two different legend for the two variable `sim` and `obs` which will be red and blue color legend respectively. Also I want to show the magnitude of the variable in the legend but not as the varying size of bubbles, but in some different way. Something like given [here](http://flowingdata.com/2010/11/23/how-to-make-bubble-charts/5-edited-version-2/). Can someone help me in achieving this?

[image]

Comment: You can have one color legend, and one size legend. You can't easily have two size legends (one for each color).

Comment: Also, i) you can't have two coordinate systems, ii) the `group` in `geom_point` isn't doing anything, iii) you probably want to scale size by area (`scale_size_area`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be okay with you to leave the size of the bubble as they are?

```
    df<-data.frame(sim=sample((20:30),10),obs=sample(25:40,10),long=rnorm(10,10,8),lat=rnorm(10,30,15))
shp <- df %>%
  gather(group, value, -long, -lat)

ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat),col="black",lwd=0.8,fill="slategray1",alpha=0.5)+
  coord_cartesian()+
  geom_point(data=shp,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,size=value, fill = group, color = group),alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

### Explanation

To get different colors for the groups, gather `obs` and `sim` into one column and specify this column as the colour aesthetic. `blue` and `red` are the default colors `ggplot2` assign for variables with two levels. So I deleted one `geom_point` and used the long form of your data instead for the remaining `geom_point`.

Comment: I think you want to avoid using your `shp` to draw a polygon. Your `shp` is the one for `geom_poin()`. Since there is no data for polygons, all you can do is to leave a graphic with data points, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to compromise with the size. I actually want only the upper legend in your answer i.e. two colors for obs and sim. Could you tell me how did you get it?

Comment: @Pulsar_534511, I added an explanation. This is actually a default behavior of `ggplot2`

Comment: okay, I was not aware of the 'gather' function! I see now how you got but still this is not what I want.

Comment: @Pulsar_534511, what exactly do you want? The figure in your link doesn't give different colors for the groups.

Comment: It does give different colors but both the legends are overlapped and they are transparent so it shows red+blue as purple color! What I want is two different legends showing red and blue color for sim and obs separately.

Comment: @hpesoj626 that link is for adding another legend giving the values of sim and obs! So basically I want three legend 1) for sim 2) for obs and 3) common legend giving the idea about the values of sim and obs. The third legend I can compromise with but two legends for sim and obs must be there in my plot.

Comment: Your question about color seems to have been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269742/in-r-is-it-possible-to-overlay-2-colours-in-a-plot-to-make-a-3rd-e-g-with-add) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746899/how-to-calculate-an-rgb-colour-by-specifying-an-alpha-blending-amount).

Comment: Also, the breakdown of the plot that you linked to is in [here](https://flowingdata.com/2010/11/23/how-to-make-bubble-charts/). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your instant help.  It worked to much extent what I wanted to do. Can you tell me how can I make the legend of size variable without color? It displays as gray color and if I chose "shape=21" then the bubbles are not filled with colors.

Comment: "*Can you tell me how can I make the legend of size variable without color? It displays as gray color and if I chose "shape=21" then the bubbles are not filled with colors.*" I don't think I understand that.