# Convert [0,1] floating-point value to hex color

Tags: python, html, colors

Is there a convenient way to convert a floating-point value in the range [0,1] to a HTML hex color using a specified gradient?

At the moment, I am using:

```
.myclass {fill:red, fill-opacity:FLOATINGVAL}
```

But this is a somewhat restrictive gradient to work with.

Comment: Did you want it in Python or in CSS?

Comment: You can generate the color resulting from your CSS trick by blending the RGB values with white.  See [this related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746899/how-to-calculate-an-rgb-colour-by-specifying-an-alpha-blending-amount).  In the accepted answer `alpha` is your `FLOATINGVAL`, `new` is RGB for red (`[255,0,0]`) and `old` is RGB for white (`[255,255,255]`).

Comment: I'm reminded of the Matplotlib gradients (see [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)). I don't necessarily need to do everything in CSS: I just need to be able to specify a colour on some kind of gradient generated through some kind of package.

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like:

```
def blend(color, alpha, base=[255,255,255]):
    '''
    color should be a 3-element iterable,  elements in [0,255]
    alpha should be a float in [0,1]
    base should be a 3-element iterable, elements in [0,255] (defaults to white)
    '''
    out = [int(round((alpha * color[i]) + ((1 - alpha) * base[i]))) for i in range(3)]

    return out

print blend([255,0,0], 0)       # [255, 255, 255]   (White)
print blend([255,0,0], 0.25)    # [255, 191, 191]
print blend([255,0,0], 0.5)     # [255, 128, 128]
print blend([255,0,0], 0.75)    # [255, 64, 64]
print blend([255,0,0], 1)       # [255,0,0]         (Red)

# Or RGB hex values instead of lists:
def to_hex(color):
    return ''.join(["%02x" % e for e in color])

print to_hex(blend([255,0,0], 0))       # ffffff    (White)
print to_hex(blend([255,0,0], 0.25))    # ffbfbf
print to_hex(blend([255,0,0], 0.5))     # ff8080
print to_hex(blend([255,0,0], 0.75))    # ff4040
print to_hex(blend([255,0,0], 1))       # ff0000    (Red)
```

In terms of how this function works with the [gradients you listed](http://matplotlib.org/_images/colormaps_reference_00.png)[1], `color` is the color at the right of the gradient bars while `alpha` is your position on the gradient bar (0.0 far left, 1.0 far right)

[1] This will only work with 2-color gradients -- your "color" and "white" (or whatever you specify `base` as) (i.e. gradients from that image like `Blues`, `Greens`, `Grays`, etc.)

You won't be able to generate gradients like `YlGnBu` with this function.