# Calculate the "sum" of two RGB colours

Tags: r, rgb, alpha, overlap

I create two colours as follows:

```
red  <- rgb(140, 35, 35, alpha=255, max=255)
blue <- rgb(35, 35, 140, alpha=0.6*255, max=255)
```

***How do I create a new colour which is obtained by overlapping the "transparent" blue over the red?***

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/746937/829571) but (a) I don't know how to apply it to an rgb object and (b) I was hoping there is a built-in way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [TheComeOnMan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724428/829571), I came up with this little function that seems to do what I need:

```
overlap <- function(under, over) {
  r1 <- strtoi(substr(under, 2, 3), base = 16)
  r2 <- strtoi(substr(over, 2, 3), base = 16)
  g1 <- strtoi(substr(under, 4, 5), base = 16)
  g2 <- strtoi(substr(over, 4, 5), base = 16)
  b1 <- strtoi(substr(under, 6, 7), base = 16)
  b2 <- strtoi(substr(over, 6, 7), base = 16)
  a  <- strtoi(substr(over, 8, 9), base = 16) / 255 # alpha

  result <- rgb(a * r2 + (1 - a) * r1,
                a * g2 + (1 - a) * g1,
                a * b2 + (1 - a) * b1,
                alpha = 255,
                max=255)
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: It seems, also, that you could replace `strtoi`s with `col2rgb(c(red, blue), TRUE)` and continue from there

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a built in way but you could just break the character string back into the original components - 
`strtoi(x = substr(red,2,3), base = 16)` + ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a built-in way. I'm assuming you want some sort of "blend" (i.e. a weighted average, possibly using the methods in the page you linked to) rather than a "sum" , since the addition There was a similar question on r-help where the the more color-savvy people pointed out that there are other colorspaces where blending colors deliver more sensible results. The method that Duncan Murdoch suggested was to convert to hsv-colorspace and let colorRampPalette do the "averaging" by picking the mid-point of line drawn across the location of those two "points":

```
# Average the 1st two by taking the middle colour of a 3 colour palette
x <- colorRampPalette(c(red,blue), space = "Lab")(3)[2]
x
[1] "#6C1F57"
> red
[1] "#8C2323FF"
> blue
[1] "#23238C99"
```

Since that only returns a three color value and no alpha, you may want to handle that separately. I'm not a color-knowledgeable useR so I cannot advise on that matter.

Comment: It doesn't seem to give the expected result - thanks for the pointer though.